tsc does not ignore node_modules files
My compiler options are:
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "allowJs": true,
      "target": "es6",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "types": []
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
  }

and yet, tsc complains about wrong types in files in the node_modules folder, and also:
src/index.ts:125:21 - error TS2802: Type 'IterableIterator<number>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher.

even though my target is set to es6.
What am I doing wrong?

How are you running tsc ? I have a feeling this is the classic mistake where it's called with a file argument.

@Evert $ node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc src/index.ts or $ npx tsc src/index.ts. Hmmm, running tsc without any arguments works. Damn, how unintuitive. Please add your comment as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks.

Yep, that's the classic mistake - if you run tsc over a file, it ignores the project configuration and just uses a default one. You also have to specify --project and give it the tsconfig file you have. It's a documented behaviour of tsc. I have no idea why, though. I think it only leads to questions like yours.

If you run tsc [filename], tsconfig.json will be ignored. To solve, simply run tsc by itself.
